# How to take one's complement of a positive integer?

Tags: computer-science, inverse, binary

Of course we can do that by converting the number to binary and then converting it back to decimal, but to do that directly in decimal?

Comment: 255 - n (for 8-bit number); $(2^8 - 1) - n$ in other words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix a maximum number of bits $b$ and then the one's complement of a positive integer $x$ with at most $b$ bits is given by $x'=2^b-1-x$, because by definition the sum $x+x'$ has all bits set and hence is of the form $2^b-1$.

If you do not fix a maximum number of bits then you can still flip all significant bits, but then the map $x\mapsto x'$ is no longer injective (and hence not invertible) because for instance $0$ and $2$ are mapped to $1$.

Comment: I think it should be $2^{b+1}-1$ if I assume MSB is not reserved for sign bit.

Comment: @AppleGrew, your question says "positive integer" and does not mention sign bit etc. But yes.